# How to create update trigger with some condition?

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g, database-trigger

I want to create a trigger which enforces condition which claims as ***details* column *may be changed only in 3 days after it placed***

```
CREATE TRIGGER BEFORE UPDATE

CREATE TRIGGER INSTEAD OF UPDATE
```

I have `OrderId`, `Details`, `OrderDate` columns

How can I do that? Can you help, please

Comment: Can you have just a wee bit more of an attempt at creating it yourself than that? Even digging out any docs for an update trigger, like https://www.techonthenet.com/oracle/triggers/before_update.php , will give you more of an idea / stab at writing this yourself than you've currently got there

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here's an example.

First, test case:

```
SQL> alter session set nls_date_format = 'dd.mm.yyyy';

Session altered.

SQL> create table test
  2    (orderid   number primary key,
  3     details   varchar2(20),
  4     orderdate date
  5    );

Table created.

SQL> insert into test (orderid, details, orderdate)
  2    select 1, 'test 1', date '2018-10-15' from dual union all
  3    select 2, 'test 2', date '2018-10-22' from dual;

2 rows created.

SQL> select sysdate from dual;

SYSDATE
----------
23.10.2018

SQL> select * from test;

   ORDERID DETAILS              ORDERDATE
---------- -------------------- ----------
         1 test 1               15.10.2018
         2 test 2               22.10.2018

SQL>
```

Trigger:

```
SQL> create or replace trigger trg_bu_test
  2    before update of details on test
  3    for each row
  4  begin
  5    if trunc(sysdate) - :new.orderdate > 3 then
  6       raise_application_error(-20001, 'More than 3 days have passed; update is not allowed');
  7    end if;
  8  end;
  9  /

Trigger created.
```

Testing:

```
SQL> -- ID = 1 - 8 days have passed, no update is allowed
SQL> update test set details = 'xxx' where orderid = 1;
update test set details = 'xxx' where orderid = 1
       *
ERROR at line 1:
ORA-20001: More than 3 days have passed; update is not allowed
ORA-06512: at "SCOTT.TRG_BU_TEST", line 3
ORA-04088: error during execution of trigger 'SCOTT.TRG_BU_TEST'


SQL> -- ID = 2 - 1 day passed - update is allowed
SQL> update test set details = 'yyy' where orderid = 2;

1 row updated.

SQL>
```

P.S. `INSTEAD OF` triggers (you mentioned in your question) are used with views; forget about them (in this case).

Comment: Everything works perfect, explained in understandable way, step by step, thank you so much

Answer (score 0):

Try using AFTER Trigger

```
create or replace TRIGGER TR_details_update
AFTER UPDATE ON order_det
REFERENCING NEW AS NEW OLD AS OLD
FOR EACH ROW

BEGIN
    IF UPDATING THEN 
        IF  NVL(:OLD.Details, 'XXX')     <>   NVL(:NEW.Details, 'XXX') AND :OLD.OrderDate <= TRUNC(SYSDATE) - 3  THEN            
               update order_det
               set Details = :new.Details
               where Details = :old.Details 
               and OrderId = :old.OrderId;
        END IF;
    END IF;
        EXCEPTION
        WHEN OTHERS THEN
    RAISE_APPLICATION_ERROR (-20000,'Details must be changed within 3 days of order date');
END TR_details_update;
```

Comment: Why an `AFTER` trigger and not a `BEFORE` trigger?

Comment: Why do you check whether you're UPDATING? What else would you do in the *after* **UPDATE** trigger? Why do you `UPDATE` within the trigger? In your code, you'd simply *do nothing*. Also, which exception do you expect? That should be part of ELSE, not EXCEPTION.

Comment: I got mutating error .. so i changed to AFTER trigger ... I went with update inside block but that is unnecessary after I saw your trigger...thanks